# change the style of element dynamically using VUEJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have **div** and I want to change its position dynamically using VueJS app.
I have variable x in data function and I want to assign it to **top**.
this is the code I write but it dosn't work
in template tag:

```
<template>
    <div id="squar" v-if="showSquar" :style="{top: x}" @click="countClicks">
        click here
    </div>  
</template>
```

and in style tag:

```
#squar{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(0,70,40,0.8);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    
    }
```

> the component that I work in isn't the **App** component

Comment: change `:style="{top: x}"` to ```:style="`top: ${x}`"``` you may also need to include `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works for me:**

```html
<template>
  <div id="squar" v-if="showSquar" :style="{ top: top + 'px' }">
    click here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showSquar: true,
      top: 200
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
#squar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(0, 70, 40, 0.8);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are binding a [style attribute](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inline-css-guide-how-to-style-an-html-tag-directly/) that won't do anything you need to write it like css

```html
<template>
    <div id="squar" v-if="showSquar" :style="`top:${x}`" @click="countClicks">
        click here
    </div>  
</template>
```

You may also need to include the [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) tag.

```
:style="`top:${x}!important`"
```